# Setting number of decimals for print via user input

Tags: python, printing, formatting

I'm dabbling around in Python and wrote a short program which returns the square root of a number provided by the user. The output, respectively the print line, looks like this:

```
print 'The square root of %d is %.2f' % (x, math.sqrt(x))
```

with x as the user input.

My question: how could i adjust the results number of decimals via user input?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even if you *print* additional digits, `math.sqrt` isn't going to compute more significant digits. Printing *less* digits will work fine, but printing *more* will just give you noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get input for how many decimal places you want it by:

```
y = int(raw_input("How many decimal places? "))
```

Then you'll probably want to use `str.format` to make your print statement easier:

```
print 'The square root of {} is {:.{dec}f}'.format(x, math.sqrt(x), dec=y)
```

I might be (I probably am) wrong here, but I'm not sure if you can do what you're trying to achieve with the `%` operator. `%` tends to be looked at as a deprecated operator anyway, especially with the majority of people transitioning to Python 3. But, since you're using Python 2, thankfully `str.format` is in Python 2.7.